Arm bootloader and kernel visualisation error
I want make tiny OS for ARM system. I have this bootloader:
.global _start

.text
_start:
    /* Set up the stack */
    ldr sp, =stack_top

    /* Call the kernel entry point */
    bl kernel_entry

    /* Infinite loop */
hang:
    b hang

.bss
.space 1024
stack_top:

And Here kernel:
void kernel_entry(void) {
    const char *msg = "Hello, ARM world!\n";
    char *uart = (char *)0x101f1000;  // UART base address for ARM

    while (*msg) {
        *uart = *msg++;
    }

    while (1);
}

I wrote make file for compiling:
all: bootloader.bin

bootloader.bin: bootloader.elf
    arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary bootloader.elf bootloader.bin

bootloader.elf: bootloader.o kernel.o
    arm-none-eabi-ld -Ttext 0x8000 -o bootloader.elf bootloader.o kernel.o

kernel.o: kernel.c
    arm-none-eabi-gcc -ffreestanding -nostdlib -c -o kernel.o kernel.c

bootloader.o: bootloader.s
    arm-none-eabi-as -o bootloader.o bootloader.s

run: bootloader.bin kernel.img
    ./run.sh

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.elf *.bin

I use command for runing qemu subsystem:
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -kernel "C:/Users/Ukraine/Documents/FlowyOS/bootloader.bin" -initrd "C:/Users/Ukraine/Documents/FlowyOS/kernel.img" -d int
And i have 'error' cuz in wm i did not see hello world text:

Any ides what can be wrong and how to fix it?

It is missing a linker script defining stack_top at the very least. Not speaking of entry point address and other memory definitions.

@EugeneSh., any examples?

In fact I found your stack_top definition in the assembly. Still might be incorrect and insufficient. As for examples - these are really easy to find. Check this for instance: https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/hello-world-for-bare-metal-arm-using-qemu/

BTW, you are sending your hello world to the UART, not to the display, so you should be seeing it in the console. But for that you need to pass something like -serial mon:stdio to qemu

while (*msg) {         *uart = *msg++;     } it is looking very wrong

@0___________ It isn't. I presume uart is pointing to the TX register. But it is wrong that uart is not defined as volatile. In fact I recently followed a similar example on OSDev that I considered trustworthy, and it has the same issue. And yes, it did not work without volatile: https://wiki.osdev.org/RISC-V_Bare_Bones .OP: Note, it is another pitfall.

@EugeneSh. there are not checks if UART is ready to get another character

@0___________ I guess the simulation just doesn't care, as if it has an infinite FIFO or something

It doesn't currently care because pl011 UART writes are sent synchronously out to the backend (in this case the terminal), so it's never possible to "fill the FIFO". However, we might model this more accurately in future, so it's not good practice to rely on it. Similarly in future we might well actually model the "you need to enable TX, RX, etc in the control register to turn the UART on" behaviour, which this code also is not doing...

strap.s
.globl _start
_start:
    mov sp,#0x20000
    bl notmain
hang:
    b hang

.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr

notmain.c
void PUT32 ( unsigned int, unsigned int );
int notmain ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    for(ra=0;;ra++)
    {
        ra&=7;
        PUT32(0x101f1000,0x30+ra);
    }
    return(0);
}

memmap
/* memmap */
MEMORY
{
    ram  : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 32K
}

SECTIONS
{
   .text : { *(.text*) } > ram
   .bss  : { *(.text*) } > ram
}

build
arm-none-eabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings -march=armv5t strap.s -o strap.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -Wall -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -march=armv5t notmain.c -o notmain.o
arm-none-eabi-ld strap.o notmain.o -T memmap -o notmain.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D notmain.elf > notmain.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy notmain.elf -O binary notmain.bin

Inspect
00000000 <_start>:
   0:   e3a0d802    mov sp, #131072 ; 0x20000
   4:   eb000002    bl  14 <notmain>

00000008 <hang>:
   8:   eafffffe    b   8 <hang>

0000000c <PUT32>:
   c:   e5801000    str r1, [r0]
  10:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000014 <notmain>:
  14:   e92d4070    push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
  18:   e3a04000    mov r4, #0
  1c:   e59f5014    ldr r5, [pc, #20]   ; 38 <notmain+0x24>
  20:   e2044007    and r4, r4, #7
  24:   e2841030    add r1, r4, #48 ; 0x30
  28:   e1a00005    mov r0, r5
  2c:   ebfffff6    bl  c <PUT32>
  30:   e2844001    add r4, r4, #1
  34:   eafffff9    b   20 <notmain+0xc>
  38:   101f1000    andsne  r1, pc, r0

To run as a bin need the entry point up front.
One way to run is
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -nographic -kernel notmain.bin

It will spew out
01234567012345670123456701234567012345670...

To stop/exit ctrl-a then x
Or
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -kernel notmain.bin

Then ctrl-alt-3 (Linux of course, if Windows I don't know how, but it's possible) to get to the serial console.
That was position independent without trying.  Let's see what is going on with the address space.
.globl GETPC
GETPC:
    mov r0,pc
    bx lr

hexstring(GETPC());

gives 0x10054 (different binary not shown).  So 0x10000 based (not 0x8000 on my machine today).
So can try this
MEMORY
{
    ram  : ORIGIN = 0x00010000, LENGTH = 32K
}

SECTIONS
{
   .text : { *(.text*) } > ram
   .bss  : { *(.text*) } > ram
}

Disassembly of section .text:

00010000 <_start>:
   10000:   e3a0d802    mov sp, #131072 ; 0x20000
   10004:   eb000002    bl  10014 <notmain>

00010008 <hang>:
   10008:   eafffffe    b   10008 <hang>

0001000c <PUT32>:
   1000c:   e5801000    str r1, [r0]
   10010:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00010014 <notmain>:
   10014:   e92d4070    push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
   10018:   e3a04000    mov r4, #0
   1001c:   e59f5014    ldr r5, [pc, #20]   ; 10038 <notmain+0x24>
   10020:   e2044007    and r4, r4, #7
   10024:   e2841030    add r1, r4, #48 ; 0x30
   10028:   e1a00005    mov r0, r5
   1002c:   ebfffff6    bl  1000c <PUT32>
   10030:   e2844001    add r4, r4, #1
   10034:   eafffff9    b   10020 <notmain+0xc>
   10038:   101f1000    andsne  r1, pc, r0

and run the elf file
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -nographic -kernel notmain.elf

And that works fine.
void notmain ( void )
{
    const char *msg = "Hello, ARM world!\n";
    char *uart = (char *)0x101f1000;  // UART base address for ARM

    while (*msg) {
        *uart = *msg++;
    }
}

A number of reasons why this should not work for language reasons, but...
00010014 <notmain>:
   10014:   e3a03048    mov r3, #72 ; 0x48
   10018:   e59f2014    ldr r2, [pc, #20]   ; 10034 <notmain+0x20>
   1001c:   e59f1014    ldr r1, [pc, #20]   ; 10038 <notmain+0x24>
   10020:   e5c13000    strb    r3, [r1]
   10024:   e5f23001    ldrb    r3, [r2, #1]!
   10028:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
   1002c:   1afffffb    bne 10020 <notmain+0xc>
   10030:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
   10034:   0001003c    andeq   r0, r1, ip, lsr r0
   10038:   101f1000    andsne  r1, pc, r0

r1 points to the uart, r2 points at the string.
It created an .rodata section even though I did not specify one.
Disassembly of section .rodata.str1.4:

0001003c <.rodata.str1.4>:
   1003c:   6c6c6548    cfstr64vs   mvdx6, [ip], #-288  ; 0xfffffee0
   10040:   41202c6f            ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x41202c6f
   10044:   77204d52            ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x77204d52
   10048:   646c726f    strbtvs r7, [ip], #-623 ; 0xfffffd91
   1004c:   Address 0x000000000001004c is out of bounds.

qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -nographic -kernel notmain.elf

Hello, ARM world!
QEMU: Terminated

You want a volatile for the uart pointer, or other solutions.  Want to have control over the linker script.
The -Ttext 0x8000 is going to take a/the stock/default linker script and basically hack it up with changing where .text lives.  You will want to just control the whole link and not do this, you can see how trivial linker scripts can be despite almost everyone grossly over complicating theirs.
If I take my binary that prints numbers out and do this
ENTRY(_start)
MEMORY
{
    ram  : ORIGIN = 0x0002000, LENGTH = 32K
}

SECTIONS
{
   .text : { *(.text*) } > ram
   .bss  : { *(.text*) } > ram
}

Telling the linker to put the entry point into the binary (other than a default of the first thing in the memory image).  And run with the elf.
00002054 

And your 0x8000 and other kernel elf images would do this as well, just to force the entry point...
b .
b .
b .
b .
b .

.globl _start
_start:
reset:
    mov sp,#0x10000
    bl notmain
hang:
    b hang


Disassembly of section .text:

00002000 <_start-0x14>:
    2000:   eafffffe    b   2000 <_start-0x14>
    2004:   eafffffe    b   2004 <_start-0x10>
    2008:   eafffffe    b   2008 <_start-0xc>
    200c:   eafffffe    b   200c <_start-0x8>
    2010:   eafffffe    b   2010 <_start-0x4>

00002014 <_start>:
    2014:   e3a0d801    mov sp, #65536  ; 0x10000
    2018:   eb000026    bl  20b8 <notmain>

0000201c <hang>:
    201c:   eafffffe    b   201c <hang>

00002020 <GETPC>:
    2020:   e1a0000f    mov r0, pc
    2024:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00002028 

So it is really using the entry point not simply executing from the start.
It may be that you simply are not looking at the console output screen.  Without seeing a disassembly/dump of your binary, it is difficult to tell why yours is not working.  Want to boot something bare-metal, disassembly and dumping the binary is examined before even trying to run.

Thx it totaly work. But i have question. When I launch qemu without gui, i have few errors:
pulseaudio: set_sink_input_volume() failed pulseaudio: Reason: Invalid argument pulseaudio: set_sink_input_mute() failed pulseaudio: Reason: Invalid argument
I got message Hello, world asm! But what that errors are telling and how i can fix it?

This answer seems to look at "where am I loaded" using a non-ELF notmain.bin file and then use the results when deciding how to arrange an ELF file. This isn't reliable, because QEMU -kernel loads raw binaries and ELF files differently (we assume raw binary is "I'm a Linux kernel, boot me like a Linux kernel says it must be booted", and ELF file is "load where the ELF file says to load"). This is a model of a real piece of hardware so the right way to decide where to load the ELF file is to look at the hardware docs of its memory map...

The pulseaudio messages, incidentally, mean "your host doesn't have pulseaudio configured correctly, so if the guest tries to record sound it won't work". You can fix up the audio setup on your host, or you can turn off QEMU's use of audio with "-audio none".

depending on how yours was built ultimately that simple of a program should have, or could have, worked even if linked at the wrong address (if run as a -O binary .bin file).

Since the question was not really complete enough to repeat to debug as is, this demonstrates a trivial, working, example.  The OP had -Ttext 0x8000 to get that working you need to know how to make that work (with a -O binary .bin or an elf file otherwise you might have partial success then hard failure).  So this answer is just trying to provide some level of you can do it too and then apply that to what you had to start with.

as I think was commented on, it may simply be that yours was working but you didnt have the console/serial string visible.
